# How to load account address from polkadot extension?

Tags: polkadot-js

I have following code so far.

```
import { useSubstrateState } from './../substrate-lib'
import { web3FromSource } from '@polkadot/extension-dapp'

const { api, currentAccount } = useSubstrateState()    
const getFromAcct = async () => {
        const {
          address,
          meta: { source, isInjected },
        } = currentAccount
    
        if (!isInjected) {
          return [currentAccount]
        }
    
      
        const injector = await web3FromSource(source)
        return [address, { signer: injector.signer }]
      }
```

And transaction as:

```
const fromAcct = await getFromAcct()
const unsub = await txExecute
              .signAndSend(...fromAcct, ({ status, events }) => {
                txResHandler(status, events)
              })
              .catch(txErrHandler)
```

But it doesn't call the polkadot extension.
It gives error `Cannot destructure property 'address' of 'currentAccount' as it is null.`

Answer (score 11):

You issue lies here -

```js
const {
  address,
  meta: { source, isInjected },
} = currentAccount
```

As the error suggests, in this case `currentAccount === null`, so trying to extract `address` from it is invalid.

Either check for the `null` value before attempting to deconstruct, or don't allow `null` returns for `currentAccount` from `useSubstrateState()`

Comment: Ya, I know. useSubstrateState() is not my library, I can't modify it, how can I get the account address without relying on the library. https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template/tree/main/src/substrate-lib

Comment: I added the <AccountSelector /> component. I have to choose the account from the list, it can't happen directly. https://polkadot.js.org/docs/extension/usage Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You should probably try the `web3Accounts` method first.

According to @polkadot/extension-dapp package's [document](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/extension-dapp/v/0.33.2), here are the differences

- `web3Accounts(): Promise<InjectedAccountWithMeta[]>` - returns a list of all the injected accounts, accross all extensions (source in meta)
- `web3FromSource(name: string): Promise<InjectedExtension>` - Retrieves a provider identified by the name

If you choose `web3FromSource`, make sure you pass to it the correct extension name.

In the case of Polkadot.js extension, the name should be `polkadot-js`:

```
const injector = await web3FromSource('polkadot-js');
```